# Is there a way to construct a deeply nested Dictionary with nice syntax and IntelliSense support?

Tags: c#, .net-core, intellisense

I am trying to create an object that contains the parsed register values of a robot. I have an ASCII text file that contains representations of the variables and arrays. However, I am struggling to think of an easy way to use the deeply nested values. Ideally, the syntax to use the deeply nested objects would be something like `Registers["PositionRegister"]["CurrentPosition"]["X_Coordinate"]` and the dictionary would be something like this:

(There was a JSON representation here of what I wanted the dictionary to look like, but people kept suggesting JSON serialization...)

However, since I am parsing the file and constructing the object at the same time, I don't know how deep the nesting will go until the parsing is complete.

I've tried using a simple Register class that can contain a dictionary of sub-Registers:

```
public class Register
    {
        public Dictionary<string, Register>? subRegisters;

        public string name { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }

    }
```

However, the usage turns into super unintuitive syntax like `motionRegister.subRegisters["Register1"].subRegisters["SubRegister1"].subRegisters["Value1"].Value` and I'm duplicating information by using the name as the key.

I've also tried using only nested Dictionaries like:

```
public Dictionary<string, object> CreateRegisters()
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> TopLevelRegisters = new();
            Dictionary<string, object> SubRegisters = new();
            Dictionary<string, object> SubSubRegisters = new();

            SubSubRegisters.Add("SubSubElement1", "5678");

            SubRegisters.Add("SubElement1", "1234");
            SubRegisters.Add("SubElement2", SubSubRegisters);
            SubRegisters.Add("SubElement3", "1357");

            TopLevelRegisters.Add("Register1", SubRegisters);

            return TopLevelRegisters;

        }
```

but they end up being super difficult to use since IntelliSense doesn't know what the object will be until runtime. I would return it as another Dictionary, but I don't know how deep the nesting will have to go.

I'm sure that there's a simple solution, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: I think you want indexing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/

Comment: That looks like json, use a json lib like json.net and deserialize it to an object. The rest will happen automagically.

Comment: If you want to have IntelliSense, then you must deserialize this JSON into an object model. I.e., classes like `PositionRegister` containing properties for `CurrentPosition` and `LastPosition` and `Location` class having `X/Y/Z_Coordinate` properties, etc.

Comment: I will take a look at indexing, it looks promising. I am not trying to deserialize from JSON. The file I am parsing is in a proprietary format that is not near as nice to work with since it isn't consistent. I am already serializing and deserializing my own data in JSON just fine. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Note that an indexer won't give you IntelliSense; nothing will do that short of compile-time generation of the parse code, which you could achieve if the parser ran as a [source generator](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview). This requires the file structure to be static, however. While you can use things like `dynamic` and `ExpandoObject` to make the code "look nicer", this too is not actual compile-time safety (and you will get mobs with torches and pitchforks after you who spit on `dynamic` as a matter of faith, but that's another matter).

Comment: Have a look at [How to serialize and deserialize (marshal and unmarshal) JSON in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing I could come up with is to

- Subclass `Dictionary<>`, and define the subclass in terms of itself (allows for arbitrary depth, and prevents the need for what you call the "unintuitive syntax" of a sub-dictionary manifesting in the path)
- Hide the existing indexer with a new implementation (allows for auto-construction of a new level)
- Provide a `Value` property for storing the value of the leaf node.
- Provide a `ToString()` that returns `Value` (allows for the elimination of `.Value` from the syntax in certain cases, such as concatenation of strings, `WriteLine`, etc.)

> NOTE: A `Name` property is dropped altogether because the name can be determined based on the dictionary key.

This code will look something like this

```
public class RecursiveDictionary : Dictionary<string, RecursiveDictionary>
{
    public string? Value { get; set; }

    public override string? ToString() => Value;

    public new RecursiveDictionary this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            if (!TryGetValue(key, out var subDictionary))
                base[key] = subDictionary = new RecursiveDictionary();
            return subDictionary;
        }

        set => base[key] = value;
    }
}
```

During parsing, you only have to output each path to a terminal `Value` or if you keep track of where you're at in the parsing, simply set the `Value` of the current (sub)dictionary. (Side note, it doesn't matter how you build it or whether the source is proprietary (your case), JSON, or some other format).

Here's an example construction:

```
var rd = new RecursiveDictionary();
rd["x"].Value = "Hi!";
rd["x"]["y"].Value = "VALUE";
rd["a"]["b"]["c"]["d"].Value = "VALUETWO";
```

Notice, I didn't have to allocate `RecursiveDictionary` for every level; this is because the `get` portion of the indexer does that for me.

From the static Intellisense (i.e. while program is not running), you can hover over `rd` and see it is a `RecursiveDictionary`,

[image]

hover over `Value` and see that it is a string,

[image]

and hover over one of the `]` or `[` and see that it is an indexer on the dictionary:

[image]

Now for the dynamic (runtime under debugger) I'm not going to show all the code for various accesses or the Intellisense for it, but I can emulate both in a watch window. What you see in the watch window below could just as easily been lines of `Console.WriteLine(...)` with you hovering over the various locations. So imagine these examples:

[image]

> CAVEAT: The `ToString()` might give you some unexpected results depending on the situation. Are you concatenating strings, are you viewing in the debugger, are you using in a `WriteLine()`, are you passing a sub-dictionary to another method, etc. If that becomes problematic, then go for a slightly less terse syntax that requires you to always get the value explicitly via the `Value` property.